# Develop notes & lists in App Actions Google Assistant

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assistant, app-actions

I've an application for Android and iOS that can be used to create grocery lists. I want to integrate the Google Assistant service with my application. I've already integrated Alexa, creating a Skill and subscribing to the events of the lists.

I would also like to integrate Google Assistant, but I can't find information about triggering events in google lists to later manage those products in my application.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Productivity Built-in Intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/productivity) -  these will allow you use the Assistant to create, get, and update list items.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this! Seems like this is in early access and requires special approval from Google - any idea on how to speed up that process?

Comment: You should be able to sign-up through the [early access program](https://assistant.google.com/business/form/).